# Contact Us page incorrectly refers to meta.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, contact, mso-mse-split

The *Contact Us* page (https://stackexchange.com/about/contact) stills refers to http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

[image]

Comment: Actually, `https://stackexchange.com/about/contact` redirects to `https://stackoverflow.com/about/contact`.